# Value in object won't change

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

```
const filterField = {
  searchText: ''
  //Empty value to change over time.
}

const renderNotes = function (notes, filters) {
  const filteredNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
    return note.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
  }) 
  console.log(filteredNotes)
}
renderNotes(habits, filterField)

//This function is supposed to change the value of the filteredField object. 
  document.querySelector('#search-text').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    filterField.searchText === e.target.value;
    renderNotes(habits, filterField);
  } )
```

The last method is supposed to change the value of the filterfield object. But it won't change.

I am following a tutorial on udemy and am stuck on this part.

Comment: `===` is comparison, assignment is `=`

Comment: I was patiently waiting to feel like an idiot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> filterField.searchText === e.target.value;
> ```

Too many equal signs:

- Double equal checks for equality (value)
- Triple equal checks for strict equality (value AND type)
- Single equal assigns

change to

> ```
> filterField.searchText = e.target.value;
> ```

Comment: Please don't post real answers to trivial errors like this. It delays the auto-deletion.